# Why can $\chi_{c}$ states not decay leptonically?

Tags: particle-physics, conservation-laws, standard-model, parity

I am trying to understand why the $\chi_{c}$ states of charmonium cannot decay to $l\overline{l}$ pairs. I believe it is because they have positive parity, but I'm unsure why this prevents the decay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a complete rewrite of my answer, kept honest by @1MegaMan1 's logically elegant comment: a tip of the hat. The lepton pair is not in a well-defined *L* state, so parity arguments relying on a special *L* are not controlling here. First for the facts.

The χ state has $J^{PC}= 0^{++}$. It comes about from $L=S=1$, so $^3P_0$. Its $C=(-)^{L+S}$. From *C*, it does not couple to one photon (with $C=-1$), so it can neither be produced or decay through a just *one* (virtual) photon state. But it *does couple to two photons*, γγ, and so its production from $e^+ e^-$ collisions and decay to a lepton pair are strictly allowed, but fantastically suppressed by $\alpha^2$. Indeed, the BR to two photons for the χ is $O(10^{-4})$. Getting a lepton pair as the abutment of two such virtual photons is a no-go, in practical terms.  It mostly decays by OZI-suppressed gluons to hadronic modes, instead.

By the way, the pseudoscalar meson, $\eta_c$, with $J^{PC}= 0^{-+}$, actually $^1S_0$, has the very same *C* problem in coupling to pairs of leptons. Again, its decay to two photons has a BR of  $O(10^{-4})$ and I'm not sure anyone has observed/could observe  the two lepton decay mode.

Comment: I know this thread is quite old, but I've got a question about this: Wouldn't it be possible for the final $l^{+}l^{-}$ state to have an orbital angular momentum of L = 1? This would give the parity of the final state as $P_f = (-1)(+1)(-1)^L = +1$ thereby conserving parity. This implies that we need the spin angular momentum of the final state to be S = 1 in order to conserve the angular momentum J = 0, i.e. the two leptons are in a triplet state with aligned spins. So it seems to me like this decay wouldn't violate any conservation laws. Where has my reasoning gone wrong?

Comment: That seems all well and good but this opens up another confusion for me: The decay of $\Delta^+ \rightarrow p^+ + \pi^0$ occurs and is the dominant decay mode according to wikipedia. $J^P$ for $\Delta^+$ is $\frac{3}{2}^+$ for $p^+$ it's $\frac{1}{2}^+$ and for $\pi^0$ it's $0^-$. This means that the only way parity and angular momentum can be conserved is by requiring that L=1 as then $J_f = 3/2$ and $P_f = P_p P_\pi (-1)^L$. But wouldn't the particles in this case (in the Delta rest frame) also have to come out back to back like in the above case so that we cannot actually have an L=1 state?

Comment: You *are* right, you kept me honest, and I will rewrite my answer. The short answer is the two lepton mode *is* allowable, but *only* through two photons, by dint of charge conjugation! It is thus vastly suppressed, by 4 orders of magnitude, in the BR, and it is still the same suppression in $e^+e^-$ production.